# LibGDX FrameBufferObject and SpriteBatch layering and transparency issue

Tags: java, android, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0, box2d

I have the following issue: When I render the fob to the screen it won't clear itself from the last time. But when I add the clear screen code, the background is not visible.

Code without clearing:

```
public void render(float delta) {

    // Temporary variable
    float zoom = camera.zoom;

    frameBufferObject.begin();
    {
        // Render
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        sb.begin();
        groundManager.render(sb);
        sb.end();
    }
    frameBufferObject.end();

    // Clear the screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.3f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Render the images
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sb.begin();
    {
        sb.draw(backgroundTexture,
                camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth * zoom / 2,
                camera.position.y - camera.viewportHeight * zoom / 2,
                camera.viewportWidth * zoom,
                camera.viewportHeight * zoom);

        sb.draw(frameBufferObject.getColorBufferTexture(),
                camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth * zoom / 2,
                camera.position.y - camera.viewportHeight * zoom / 2,
                camera.viewportWidth * zoom,
                camera.viewportHeight * zoom,
                0, 0, 1, 1);

        // Render the ground
        surfaceFragmentManager.render(sb);
    }
    sb.end();
}
```

Has this output:
[image]

But when I add

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.3f, 1f);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

It just clears the screen and draws the background with a solid color.

How could I make fob clear itself, and have the background visible?

Thank you.

Comment: After you call `frameBufferObject.begin()` you can simply call `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.3f, 1f);` and `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` This will clear your framebuffer with the Color you gave to `glClearColor`.

Answer (score 0):

After painful 3 hours, the answer was as simple as adding the following fragment at the beginning of the FBO

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```